# How to output iso week and year from bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I've set up a simple script to output the current year and concatenate it with the current ISO week.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Date.prototype.getWeekNumber = function(){
    var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth(), this.getDate()));
    var dayNum = d.getUTCDay() || 7;
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 4 - dayNum);
    var yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(),0,1));
    return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7)
  };
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<h5 id="YYWW">Current ISO Week (YYWW) - <span  class="text-bold"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)); document.write(new Date().getWeekNumber());</script></span></h5>
```

How do I select the date (current or future) and have it output the YYWW? I want users to be able to select dates in the future, not just for the current YYWW.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <h5><label for="utm_date"><strong>ISO Date (by Datepicker)</strong></label></h5>
    <input type="week" id="datepicker" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

I have a codepen **[here](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/YOWgYL)** I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

On change of input field value, you can extract the week number & year and then you can show it to the user. (Considering you're using jquery)

```
$('input[id=datepicker]').change(function() {
  var val = $("#datepicker").val();
  var splitArr = val.split("-");
  var finalVal = splitArr[0].substring(splitArr[0].length-2, splitArr[0].length) + splitArr[1].substring(splitArr[1].length-2, splitArr[1].length);
  $("#selectedWeek").text(finalVal);

});
```

Updated [**Codepen Example**](https://codepen.io/shantanu_kulkarrni/pen/WgGoxX)

Note: Which bootstrap datepicker library you're using? Currently I've made changes considering chrome native datepicker. Tell me library & I'll update the code